# gwt validation - Violations are not picked up if annotations are present on more than 1 field

Tags: gwt

I am running this code. If I add validation annotations to 1 field, the violation is picked up correctly. But, if I add annotations on more than 1 field, no violations are picked up at all.

```java
public class Address implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 225035939665473333L;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50, message="test")
    private String Name;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String AddressLine1;

    private String AddressLine2;
    private String PostalCode;
    private String Province;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String Country;

    //getter and setters below this line
}
```

I am running this code:

```java
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure().buildValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
Address a = new Address();
a.setName("a");

Set<ConstraintViolation<Address>> violations = validator.validate(a);

Window.alert(String.valueOf(violations.size()));
for(ConstraintViolation<Address> violation : violations){
    Window.alert(violation.getMessage());
}
```

This will pick up zero errors, even if it should pick up 3 errors. AddressLine1, Country should not be null. Name is too short. If I change the class to code below, it will pick up that the name is too short and display the error message "test".

```java
public class Address implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 225035939665473333L;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50, message="test")
    private String Name;

    private String AddressLine1;

    private String AddressLine2;
    private String PostalCode;
    private String Province;

    private String Country;

    //getter and setters below this line
}
```

Comment: It works when I compile the code, but this is a bug that only happens in development mode. If I close eclipse and reopen it, it works (until I make a new change to the annotations. Then I have to restart again).